# how to correctly apply ContainerRequestFilter using Jersey on Tomcat

Tags: jakarta-ee, jersey, servlet-filters

I am using Jersey and Tomcat to create a RESTful API.

I want to apply a CustomContainerRequestFilter (which implements ContainerRequestFilter) to each request.

So I've added

```
<init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.CustomContainerRequestFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
```

The problem is that the implementation of filter() method is not triggered at all although the CustomContainerRequestFilter is being instantiated after deployment.

Did I forget to do something in order that filter to get called on each Rest method?

Comment: Hello, you should add more of your web.xml file and show us your CustomContainerRequestFilter, that would help to help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you annotate your ContainerRequestFilter implementation with a @Provider annotation